# CMSimple_XH PHP 5.5

Tags: php

So I have been searching for this on google for quite a while now but I can't seem the find the asnwers so I decieded to ask my questions here.
Does CMSimple_XH work with PHP 5.5 if so is there a way to make it reveal all the errors in the code?

Comment: as the if none out where you how i can so what for could?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably encountered a problem with a blank screen, like i had as well.
There is a very easy way to fix that.

try this page:
http://www.cmsimple-xh.org/wiki/doku.php/troubleshooting

It basically says you should create a file with the name "_XHdebug.txt" and put a number from 0 to 6 in it. nothing else.
0 will debugg nothing, and 6 will debugg everything you can think of.
Upload that file in your installation-folder and it should be fixed.

That's it!